# WP8 determining page navigation history

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In my windows phone 8 app, I am navigating among pages. say

From `MainPage`(*some user control a click to*) -> **Page1** then with a key press it will take me to **main page** back again

From `MainPage`(*some user control b click to*) -> **Page2** and then back with the key press to **main page** again and so on to **page3**, **page4** etc.

Here I want to identify from which page the main page is loaded from?

Say **page1**, **page2** or **page3** based on that I want to load the user controls according to navigation history.

I could not found any built-in property or function in a library.

Any help, I am looking for best practice as well to achieve such functionality.

Comment: you can have a global variable.before navigating to main page you need to change its value with pagename.

Comment: No inbuilt feature which directly give which was the last page your navigated from?

Comment: Please read edits and it would be great if you can give an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use back stack for this kind of purposes.

[How to navigate using the back stack for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394012%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000977/942286

Comment: @sunder By using back stack you can get previous page. What else do you need?

Comment: I don't need previous pages in back stack. I need from which page I came from in back stack. Say I navigated from main page's user control tap event to page2. then back from in this case I am coming back from page2. Hope you understood the question now?

Comment: @sunder Not sure if I still understood what you mean. Back stack tracks your navigation history. If you came from page2 to mainpage, you can use back stack in mainpage's OnNavigatedTo method and see that the user came from page2.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an

```
enum PageType
{
    NONE,
    PAGE_1,
    PAGE_2,
    PAGE_3,
    PAGE_4
}
```

Then in your `MainPage`  you can have a ivar as

```
private PageType pageType = PageType.NONE;
```

Then when you move to a page you can set it

```
pageType = PageType.PAGE_!;
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

and when you come back to `MainPage` then you can have this

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        switch (pageType)
        {
            case PageType.NONE:
                //Your code
                break;
            case PageType.PAGE_1:
                //Your code
                break;
            case PageType.PAGE_2:
                //Your code
                break;
            case PageType.PAGE_3:
                //Your code
                break;
            case PageType.PAGE_4:
                //Your code
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

You can then use navigation context.

In your user control

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page1.xaml?PAGE_TYPE=Page1", UriKind.Relative));
```

In your MainPage

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        String pageType = null;
        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("PAGE_TYPE", out pageType);
        if (pageType == "Page1")
        {
            //Your code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is would be very easy but I am not navigating directly from main page, I am navigating from user controls in main page on tap of that I am loading different pages. I would have created an event when page navigating but I have lots of user controls in app.

Comment: @sunder I have edited my answer. I'm not sure whether `NavigationContext` retains the value when coming back from the page. Please try this and if it works then good if not then use above solution in a `Singleton` class.

Answer (score 0):

make hashtable global.

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.Add("page1");
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the [NavigationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) doesn't contain the information you need, as well as the [NavigatingCancelEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.navigation.navigatingcanceleventargs%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) parameter coming with [OnNavigatingFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatingfrom%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

So unfortunately, it seems there's no builtin feature addressing your need.

However , what you could do is to persist the last page your user has been (to handle tombstoning scenarios). For instance it could be in AppSettings, here is a pseudo code :

```
public class WhateverYouWantLastPagePersister
{
    private const string LastPageID = "LastPage";

    public string GetLastPage()
    {
        string lastPage = string.Empty;
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue<string>(LastPageID, out lastPage);
        return lastPage;
    }

    public void PersistLastPage(string lastPage)
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[LastPageID] = lastPage;
    }
}
```

To persist "automatically" your last visited page, you can derive from PhoneApplicationPage and override [OnNavigatingFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatingfrom%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to create a your own base page :

```
  public class BasePage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
            Uri currentUri = ((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.CurrentSource;
            WhateverYouWantLastPagePersister.PersistLastPage(CustomMethodToExtractPageNameFromUri(currentUri));
        }
    }
```

All pages needing to persist the last visited pages have to derived from it (so Page1, Page2...)

Finally you can use *`WhateverYouWantLastPagePersister`*`.GetLastPage()` to get what you need.

Of course, in these pseudo code samples :

- lastPage can be of any type you want (string, enum , int and so
  on...), you just need an appropriate custom converter from string to anything you want
- `CustomMethodToExtractPageNameFromUri` is a simple string parser
- *`WhateverYouWantLastPagePersister`* can be static class, a singleton, injected with a DI framework, it's up to you!

Answer (score 0):

If you must know what page you came from, you can use [PhoneApplicationService.Current.State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.state%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Within your secondary pages, override OnBackKeyPress and set the value

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
    PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["LastPage"] = this; 
}
```

Then in the MainPage, you would override OnNavigatedTo and check the value of the state

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    object lastPage;
    if((e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back) &&
        (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.TryGetValue("LastPage", out lastPage)))
    {
        // we navigated back and we know what the last page was!
        var pageName = lastPage.GetType().Name;
        if (pageName == "Page1")
        {
            // do something!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass parameters when you are navigating back to main page, maybe an enum type contains 'page1' 'page2' ...